# specify an import path in react.js

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to access a function from one folder to other folder but unable to do it.
Getting Error : Cannot find module 'server/services/storagequeue'

Solution tried:

```
import { readQueueMessage } from 'server/services/storagequeue';
```

[Folder Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjIcS.png)

From this folder structure, i am trying to use readQueueMessage function from storagequeue.ts which is under server/services in the file thunk.queuepolling.ts.

Note i have used export keyword for readQueueMessage function.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank You in Advance,

Comment: Relative file paths start with `./` or `../`. Looks like you want `../../../../server/`, or use webpack aliases to abstract that away

Comment: @AndyRay I tried this but it is erroring out "ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/mkdirs-sync.js 3:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in ...." , "BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be more likely you are trying to implement a storage queue logic and trying to call that queue uploading or downloading to other folder or file. The ideal and the best way to do achieve this is using routes.

You can create a route.ts file and call that logic in route

```
queueRoute.get('/readQueueMessage', async (req: Request, res: Response, next) => {res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');try {
const result = await readQueueMessage();
res.json({ data: result });} catch (err) {
logMessage(LogLevel.ERROR, err);
res.status(500).json({ error: err });}});
```

And you can call

```
fetch('/readQueueMessage')
```

or create an action file to call that route and pass it in the destination you are trying to use.

Thank You,